# Add extra attribute on new Option element and pass attribute to href

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an extra attribute to `new Option()` so that I can pass the value to `href`.

```
    for(var i =0; i < response.data.length; i++)
    {
      pages[i] = new Option(response.data[i].name,response.data[i].access_token);
    }
```

right now the option looks like this

```
<option value ="access_token">name</option>
```

the final result should look more like this

```
<option value ="access_token" data-id="id">name</option>
```

then with a second script I collect the values and pass to an href

```
var access_token = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
var link = "next_page.php?access_token=" + access_token;
var element = document.createElement("a");
element.setAttribute("href", link);
```

right now href looks like this

```
<a href="next_page.php?access_token=access_token"></a>
```

The href end result should grab new attribute

```
<a href="next_page.php?access_token=access_token&data_attribute=data"></a>
```

Comment: you can read and write custom data attributes on an HTML element using the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, once you have your extra attribute (whatever it is) just add it to the link: `var link = "next_page.php?access_token=" + access_token + "&" + extraAttribute;`

Comment: @freginold: I need to generate the attribute dynamically  in the for loop

Comment: @Hamms : looks good but how to attach in the for loop?

Comment: `pages[i].dataset.id = "id"`. As far as the question of generating the attribute dynamically, that's a separate question and one that will require quite a few more details from you on what you want this attribute to be. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript might be what you're looking for

Comment: @Hamms : the attribute is generated by the response from the function so I'm going to try this out right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(pages[i] = new Option('_name_','_value_')).dataset['id'] = '_id_';`

This will work in FF, but unfortunately doesn't allow chainning.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This works. What do you mean by chaining? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: And since it was part of the question to attach to href should I create the variable like this : `var dataset = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset; ` ?

Comment: channing means you can not repeat it for more attributes in the same row because Option object is not returned after `=` operator, so you can not do another `.dataset` as a chain. You can add it on a new line as `pages[i].dataset['attrib2'] = '_attrib2_value_'`. `dataset` which is a DOMStringMap object does not allow adding multiple data attribs at once, per instance using `pages[i].dataset.push({attr1: val1, attr2: val2})`.

Comment: ...surfed many SO pages that gave advice that proved to be unhelpful.  The posts were using `.data(...)` and `.attr(...)` -- but those techniques kept yielding ".data/.attr is not a function".  This was the only one that properly added my `data-` attribute after `new Option()`.